# How to hide the image of a single product on a specific pages in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have woo commerce site, but in few specific product pages i don't want to show products images. How can i hide product image in specific pages only? once hide/remove product image, need to speared the text/content.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with this simple code:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'single_product_remove_images', 1 );
function single_product_remove_images() {
    // HERE below set your Page ID, title or slug
    if( is_page( 56 ) ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> If you want to target a post id istead, you will use something like `if( get_the_id() == 56 ){`